# Why do Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models (DDPM) add noise according to $\sigma_t$ during sampling?

Tags: probability, sampling, conditional-probability, generative-models, differential-equations

Reading about Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models (DDPM) [the paper (algorithm 2 - sampling)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) states that the sampling goes according to...

$$
x_{t-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha_t}}\left( x_t - \frac{1 - \alpha_t}{\sqrt{1 - \bar{\alpha}_t})}\epsilon_\theta(x_t, t) \right) + \sigma_tz, \;\;\; \text{where, } z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)
$$

WHat I am having trouble understanding is this... Why is the noise added at the end according to $\sigma_t$? The term immediately before that seems to go through the trouble of:

1. Predicting the noise which may have been added at timestep t with $\epsilon_\theta$
2. Scaling and removing the noise from $x_t$
3. Scaling the mean to bring the mean back out to where it should be at $x_{t-1}$
4. Then it seems to me that it adds back in the noise which we just worked hard to remove...Why?

Answer (score 1):

I also searched long for an answer to this question but managed to convince myself that this is similar to the StyleGAN model. In StyleGAN, we also sample from a Gaussian distribution (just as we do in DDPM, $x_T$). Then, when we are passing the model through the network, we add some noise to induce some fine details such as the details of human hair.

I don't have a rigorous explanation but it seemed me slightly similar. Hope I can convince you as well :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/347438)

Comment: thanks for adding your opinion. I can convince myself of similar ideas, but I still need to find a rigorous answer to this because its just too random. It also looks similar to the pattern of SGLD and SGMCMC and I think its possible it might be related to that as well. Not sure about StyleGAN

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same confusion and found the answer on page 4 of the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf).

As the paper explains, the goal is to sample form the distribution $x(t-1) \sim p_\theta(x(t-a)|x(t))$, not just have an exact calculation.

The authors assumed that this distribution is normally distributed with mean given by (eq.11) and variance sigma(t).

One way to achieve the sampling is by following the formula in the paper: Take the mean (eq.11) and add to it random perturbation with variance sigma(t).
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am still confused. It would make sense to me if it was $\sigma_{t-1}$. The reason is that 1) we predict and subtract the noise at $x_t$ 2) we scale the mean according to the diffusion process to achieve the mean of what we predict is $x_{t-1}$. 3) we add the noise expected at $x_{t-1}$ which would be $\sigma_{t-1}$ and not $\sigma_t$. Adding noise from $\sigma_t$ seems like we are adding in the noise which we just did hard work in removing...

Answer (score 1):

In the reverse process of a diffusion model, we start by sampling $\mathbf{x}_T$ from the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_T; \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$ then iteratively sample from our approximation to the "tractable" posterior distribution $p_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}|\mathbf{x}_t)=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1};\mu_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_t,t),\sigma^2_t\mathbf{I})$, which is a normal distribution itself when $\beta_t$s are small in the forward diffusion process.

Using the re-parameterization trick for the normal distribution, we can write a sample $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}$ from $p_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}|\mathbf{x}_t)$ as $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}=\mu_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_t,t)+\sigma_tz$. This is exactly what Algorithm 2 in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239) is doing. The first term in the equation is the mean of the tractable posterior distribution in terms of $\epsilon_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_t, t)$. As [y.mazari](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/394779/y-mazari) has rightly pointed out.

As to why the variance is $\sigma^2_t$ and not $\sigma^2_{t-1}$ look at the forward diffusion kernel
$q(\mathbf{x}_{t}|\mathbf{x}_{t-1})=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_{t};\sqrt{1-\beta_t}\mathbf{x}_{t-1},\beta_t\mathbf{I})$. One could argue it should be $\beta_{t-1}$ instead of $\beta_{t}$ since we are starting from $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}$. In one case they set $\sigma_{t}^2=\beta_t$. Now, using $\sigma_{t-1}^2$ in the tractable posterior would lead to inconsistency in the $t$'s. I think it is just semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I was also confused and let me just try to chime in. So here are 2 ways I like to think about it.

1): Intuitively, since the model is deterministic, and it is supposed to undo the forward diffusion process, which is inherently random, the only proper way to undo a random process is with another random process. This noise also helps avoid mode collapse akin to the stochastic gradient Langevin dynamics that is used in score-matching models.

2): Here is a lecture video given by Professor Sahai from UCB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_XcdM4YEXo&list=PLnocShPlK-FtgkldBYqbiNTa5bfjH-cHd&index=28. I think he did a really good job explaining the intuition behind this noise term.

In short, if we assume the input image vector is also Gaussian, we can derive the closed form $P(x_{t-1} | x_{t})$, and the noise term is needed to restore not just the mean but also the variance of the original distribution.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The reverse process is works by sampling from the distribution $q(x_{t - 1} | x_t, x_0)$, but with $x_0$ replaced by an estimate.

The distribution $q(x_{t - 1} | x_t, x_0)$ is an isotropic Gaussian with mean $\mu (x_t, x_0)$ and variance $\sigma_t = \frac{(1 - \alpha_t) (1 - \bar{\alpha}_{t-1})}{(1 - \bar{\alpha}_t)}$ (see p12 of [Luo's "Understanding Diffusion Models: ... "](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.11970)).
However, we don't have access to $x_0$, so we need to estimate it by some $\widehat{x}_0$.  We do this indirectly, by estimating the noise added to $x_0$ to obtain $x_t$ (p15, same manuscript).  The sampling formula you quote from the DDPM paper is exactly sampling from an isotropic Gaussian with mean $\mu(x_t, \widehat{x}_0)$ and variance $\sigma(t)$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, my main point of confusion remains. It seems to me that $\epsilon_\theta$ is predicting the noise which is added at $x_t$. After subtracting in the parentheses, this means we would have our estimate of $\mu(x_t)$. But then if we add $\sigma_t z$ back to $\mu(x_t)$, then it seems we just cancelled out the important work we did in predicting $\mu(x_t)$. Have I missed something important?